# How do I make cumin and herb cheese at home?

Tags: spices, herbs, cheese-making

I would like to make cumin and herb cheese at home without using any special cheese-making equipment.

- At what stage should I add my cumin and herbs?
- Which herbs should I use?
- Should I use fresh or dried herbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on what kind of cheese you are making.

I will assume that you are making a standard, medium-firm, rennet-set cheese.

I have had the most success adding seasonings and herbs with the salt. That is- after the curd has set, been cut, and drained but before it has been pressed at all. Work in the salt and any other flavors before placing the curd in the mold.

I imagine any herb or spice would work- it depends what flavor you want. I have used basil when I had a bumper crop. I have also used dried peppers.

As to dry or fresh- either would work. As with anything if you use dry then use a lot less. I prefer fresh because it is more tender.

Other cheeses might be a little different but as a rule of thumb adding with the salt should work. Mozzarella seems like it would be trickier because the kneading of the curd would change things.